# How to load multiple div without freezing the app in angular 4

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6

I wanted to create a table like structure in angular using div, rather than table. Say i have 1000 rows and 1000 column, so all to-gather  1000000 cells. When i run the program it got frozen. Please give any suggestion i could do this. I used 'flex' for rows to display next to each other.

Note: I have used 'trackBy' also, still i am getting frozen. And also Virtual scroll or lazy loading method wont be needed in my scenario.

Comment: You might want to use [Virtual Scrolling](https://material.angular.io/cdk/scrolling/overview) that was introduced in Angular 7 in the CDK.

Comment: have you tried **angular virtual scroll**?

Comment: @SiddAjmera i have gone through it and lazy loading options, but unfortunately according to my requirement, virtual scrolling cant be used

Comment: @JohnVelasquez i have gone through it and lazy loading options, but unfortunately according to my requirement, virtual scrolling cant be used

Comment: Creating a table that large will inevitably come with some performance issues, and may well crash the browser. Perhaps if you share the code you are using to iterate and draw the rows we can help you optimize it so it is more performant.

Answer (score 0):

Use `ngx-virtual-scroller`

Virtual Scroll displays a virtual, "infinite" list. Supports horizontal/vertical, variable heights, & multi-column.

[Github and example](https://github.com/rintoj/ngx-virtual-scroller)

Comment: Hi, the answer adds nothing to already existent comments. It's also discouraged to answer with just a link, since it can break on time

Comment: i have gone through Virtual Scrolling and lazy loading options, but unfortunately according to my requirement, virtual scrolling cant be used